# Create folder on remote machine using Powershell - how do I add credentials?

Tags: windows, powershell

I used the powershell script below to try and create a folder on a remote machine

```
$ComputerName = "<IP>"
$DriveLetter = "C"
$Path = "TempFolder\TestPath"
New-Item -Path \\$ComputerName\$DriveLetter$\$Path -type directory -Force
```

When I change the ComputerName to localhost, the script is executed and the intended folder is created. However, when I run this script for an IP in the same network, which I can ping, the script runs but the folder isn't created.

Do you need to provide login credentials for the remote machine somewhere in the script?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed you do:

```
PS C:> help new-item

NAME
    New-Item

SYNTAX
    New-Item [-Path] <string[]> [-ItemType <string>] [-Value <Object>] [-Force] [-Credential <pscredential>] [-WhatIf]
    [-Confirm] [-UseTransaction]  [<CommonParameters>]

    New-Item [[-Path] <string[]>] -Name <string> [-ItemType <string>] [-Value <Object>] [-Force] [-Credential
    <pscredential>] [-WhatIf] [-Confirm] [-UseTransaction]  [<CommonParameters>]

ALIASES
    ni
```

the important part is `-Credential <pscredential>`. To create this object from plain text for example:

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString 'password' -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ('username', $password)
```

There are other more secure ways to do this if you search around the net on how to create a `PSCredential` object.

Comment: thank you for your response! would the <pscredential> be a combination of username and password, something like '.\admin' 'abc@123' ?

Comment: @s_om Good question, added it to the answer.